# Casting a Web Control taken from a GridView cell in VB6

Tags: vb.net, gridview, casting

In C# when I **programmatically** need to get a specific control from a `GridView`, I insert in my `RowDataBound` event handler:

```
HyperLink hl = e.Row.Cells[n].Controls[0] as HyperLink;
```

How can I get the same result in **VB**? I tried:

```
Dim hl = CType(e.Row.Cells(n).Controls(0), HyperLink)
```

and

```
Dim hl as HyperLink = CType(e.Row.Cells(n).Controls(0), HyperLink)
```

but they do not work.

*Error 6    Value of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink'.*

Anybody know if that is possible?

Comment: Erm, in VB6? VB6 has no concept of web UI/ASP controls. I presume you mean VB.NET?

Comment: Well I have been given a web project and I've been told to modify some functionalities. I am new to VB and the person who gave me the project told me that is developed in VB6. Probably is VB.NET

Comment: I've only heard of devs not knowing what language they are programming in...

Comment: @CiccioMiami: Can you confirm and update your question to suit? VB6 and VB.Net are VERY different environments and languages.

Comment: There is no question that code posted above is running with .Net, and not vb6, for two reasons. **1)** We know it's a web app, and the legacy asp language is **not** technically vb6, but rather vbscript. **2)** Old vbscript would not throw an error complaining about "System.Web.UI...."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [TryCast()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyy863x8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) operator. It is the direct equivalent to C#'s `as` operator.

```
Dim hl As Hyperlink = TryCast(e.Row.Cells(n).Controls(0), HyperLink)
```